# Monit Webmin service is not activating

Tags: monit

I have written a script in monit interface for Webmin service. I can execute the process where in I am unable to restart the service.

```
check process webmin with pidfile /var/webmin/miniserv.pid
    start  = "/etc/init.d /webmin start"  
    stop   = "/etc/init.d /webmin stop"
    if failed host in1.miracletel.com port 10000 then restart
    if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
    #if changed pid 2 times within 2 cycles then alert
```

Would you please look into this and let me know, whether I can considered the service correct or not?

Comment: select your code and apply the code option to it. will look better.

Answer (score 0):

Looks a little different from mine:

```
   root@wl183004:/home/marc.riera/scripts/admin/trunk/src/bin# cat ../etc/monit/conf.d/apache.conf 
   check process apache with pidfile /var/run/apache2.pid
   group www-data
   start program = "/etc/init.d/apache2 start"
   stop program  = "/etc/init.d/apache2 stop"
   if failed host server.org port 80 protocol http
      and request "/monit/token" then restart
   if cpu is greater than 60% for 2 cycles then alert
   if cpu > 80% for 5 cycles then restart
   if totalmem > 500 MB for 5 cycles then restart
   if children > 250 then restart
   if loadavg(5min) greater than 10 for 8 cycles then stop
   if 3 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```

may be "start program" instead of only "start"??

Comment: I have tired working on start program, but the status show as "Execution failed".

Comment: I just wanted to know, what are all the process can be done in Monit, could you please confirm

Answer (score 0):

## My /etc/monit.d/webmin.monit.conf

Note these directories apply to CentOS (5.8, i686/32 bit) w/ Webmin 1.580. Change according to your system &, as always, YMMV.

```
check process webmin with pidfile /var/webmin/miniserv.pid 
   group webmin
   start program = "/etc/init.d/webmin start"
   stop  program = "/etc/init.d/webmin stop"
   if failed host localhost port 10000 then restart
   if failed host localhost port 10000 then restart
   if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
   if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then alert

check file webmin_rc with path /etc/init.d/webmin
   group webmin
   if failed checksum then unmonitor
   if failed permission 755 then unmonitor
   if failed uid root then unmonitor
   if failed gid root then unmonitor
```